# Union of sets dillema

Tags: number-theory

The union of sets $A$ and $B$, written $A \cup B$, is made of all elements belonging to set $A$ or set $B$.

I can’t understand this only one thing, why the union (is not made of all elements of set $A$ AND $B$?

For ex : $A=\{1,2,3\}$, $B=\{1,2,3,4\}$, $A \cup B =\{1,2,3,4\}$, why is not the union of $A$ AND $B$ instead of $A$ OR $B$?

I know the intersection is the set of all elements that belong to A AND B ,but I can’t see the difference …

Comment: "why the union is not made of all elements of set A AND B?" -- The set of all elements which belong to $A$ and to $B$ has another name. The intersection, $A \cap B$.

Comment: Think about this example: set $A$ contains elements $1, 2, 3$ (as in your example), set $B$ contains elements $1,2,3,4$. Put **ALL** these elements in one "black box" (aka union of these sets). Now, bring a **blind man** in the front of that black box. He will take just one element from that black box. What we know? We know, for sure, that he will took one element. It will be from set $A$ **OR** from set $B$.

Comment: In your example you see that $4$ belongs to $A\cup B$. Do you really, truly, seriously believe that $4$ belongs to $A$ **AND** $B$? By the way, you misspelled "dilemma."

Answer (score 0):

The difference is in the restriction we have for set membership. When we say the set of elements of $A$ and $B$, we require that a every member of this set to be a member of both $A$ and $B$ at the same time. So in your example, the set of $A$ and $B$ corresponds to
$$\{ 1,2,3 \}$$
since these are the members that are **both** in $A$ and $B$

On the other hand, the set of members that are in $A$ or $B$ are members that at least one of them belongs to $A$ or $B$. Now it may be possible that a member of this set is in both $A$ and $B$, but that is not necessary. In this example, the set $A$ or $B$ corresponds to
$$\{1,2,3,4 \}$$
If you notice, $4$ is only in $B$ but not $A$. Therefore, we can see that to be a member of $A$ or $B$, we have a lower threshold for set membership compared to $A$ and $B$, and that is why $$(A \cap B) \subseteq (A \cup B)$$
I hope this helps.

Comment: Sets A or B corresponds to {1,2,3,4} It’s  not the union of  A and B that corresponds to {1,2,3,4}. ?

Comment: "The union of $A$ and $B$" and "the set whose members are either in $A$ or $B$ (or both)" have the same meaning.

Comment: Set A ={1,2,3} ,set B={4,5,6} = A U B ={1,2,3,4,5,6}  ,how A U B can be A or B and not A and B?

Comment: If you think about it, $\{ 1,2,3,4,5,6 \}$ are exactly the members that are either in $A$ or $B$, which is equivalent to $A \cup B$. 
On the other hand, there is no member that is both in $A$ and $B$. Therefore, $A \cap B = \emptyset$. (Assuming $A=\{ 1,2,3\}$ and $B=\{4,5,6, \}$.

Comment: Ok so what if you  take A= {0,1,2} ,B={0,1,2} , A U B is not all elements of A AND B

Comment: Ok so what if you  take A= {0,1,2} ,B={0,1,2} = A U B ={0,1,2} ,is not all elements of A AND B? It’s all element of A or  B? Im cofusing something

Comment: In this case, because $A=B$, we have $A \cup B = A \cap B =\{ 0,1,2\}$.

Answer (score 0):

This is perhaps more a matter of linguistics:

- All elements of $A$ are elements of $A\cup B$ **AND** all elements of $B$ are elements of $A\cup B$ **AND** nothing else is.
- An object $x$ is element of $A\cup B$ if and only if $x$ is an element of $A$ **OR** $x$ is an element of $B$.

Apart from that, we of course say that $A\cup B$ is the union of $A$ **and** $B$, just like we say that $10$ is the sum of $7$ **and** $3$, or the product of $2$ **and** $5$, or the difference of $13$ **and** $3$, or the quotient of $50$ **and** $5$.